# a question about sequence and series. prove $ \lim_{n \to \infty}( n\ln n)a_{n}=0$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, divergent-series, cauchy-sequences

Suppose $a_{n}>0$. $na_{n}$ is monotonic, and it approaches 0 as n approaches infinity. $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{n}$ is convergent. please prove $$ \lim_{n \to \infty} n\ln(n)\,a_{n}=0$$

I totally don't know how to solve it? Can somebody tell me how to solve it?

Maybe the problem is that how to handle the $\ln n$,if we can find a method cancel $\ln n$ ,then it will work.

Comment: Does $nlnn$ stand for $n\ln(n)$?

Comment: yes,you are right

Comment: Please provide some personal input (if really you "totally don't know how to solve" the numerous questions you ask on the site, something is going wrong).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose not.  Then there is $\epsilon > 0$ such that $n \ln(n) a_n > \epsilon$ for infinitely many $n$.  For any fixed positive integer $k$, take $n > k$ for which $n \ln(n) a_n > \epsilon$ and so large that
$$\sum_{j=k}^n \dfrac{1}{j} \ge \dfrac{\ln(n)}2$$  For $k \le j \le n$ we have
$a_j \ge n a_n/j$, so 
$$  \sum_{j=k}^n a_j \ge  n a_n \sum_{j=k}^n \dfrac{1}{j} \ge \dfrac{n a_n \ln(n)}{2} > \dfrac{\epsilon}{2}$$
and therefore $\sum_j a_j$ diverges.

Comment: Yes， that's a good method!

Answer (score 0):

Can you clarify whether this is a homework question?

I will reply as if it were.  The following question and its answer will inspire you.  Suppose that $a_n$ is a monotonous sequence, $a_n\geq 0$, such that $\sum a_n < \infty.$ Then

$$\lim na_n=0.$$

Indeed, the following tends to zero as $n\to \infty$:

$$a_{n+1}+\cdots +a_{2n},$$ and at the same time one sees that the above is

$$\geq n a_{2n},$$ and since $n a_{2n} \geq n a_{2n+1}$, we have proven $k a_k\to 0$ as $k$ goes to infinity.

This will help.

Comment: "This will help." Not sure about that. I see the points which need to be modified to adapt the proof in your post to the present question--and I fear these are too much.

Comment: Actually, there's one criterion that may be applied and, together with the above, quickly leads to a solution.  However, one need have a bunch of convergence criteria at hand.